# Retrieve the attributes passed to a factory within the definition method - Laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-factory

I've been trying to find a way to retrieve the attributes passed to a factory within the definition method but have no luck, I first attempted to access the $this->states property (within the definition method) which returns a closure and then attempted to retrieve the attributes from there but have had no luck with this.

I am currently using the factories below:-

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Developer;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Developer>
 */
class DeveloperFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Specify the corresponding model for the factory
     *
     * @var string $model
     */
    protected $model = Developer::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->firstName
        ];
    }

    public function configure()
    {
        $this->afterCreating(function (Developer $developer) {
            User::factory()->create([
                'userable_type' => $developer->getMorphClass(),
                'userable_id' => $developer->id
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        /**
         * TODO: get any attributes that are passed into this factory
         * e.g.userable_type, userable_id
         * 
         * If these attributes are passed into the factory, stop the faker randomly generating a
         * factory for a random user type and use the one passed into the factory
         */
        $userableModel = (new $this->faker->userTypeModel)->factory()->create();

        return [
            'userable_type' => $userableModel->getMorphClass(),
            'userable_id' => $userableModel->id,
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => bcrypt('admin1234'), // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the model's email address should be unverified.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    public function unverified()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'email_verified_at' => null,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to get them?